# Illegal access Error java

Tags: java

I have a class

```
public Class Foobar{
     public void methodA();
}
```

Now I have a method in another class

```
public static final void callFooBar(){
   Foobar foobar = new Foobar();
   foobar.methodA(); <-- error here
}

Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method package.FooBar.methodA([Ljava/lang/String;)V from class package.mainclass
```

Any suggestions
(Sorry a newbie here)

Comment: I have doubts that the code you have provided to illustrate your problem is representative of your problem.  Are you sure you didn't type `Foobar.methodA()`?

Comment: Don't you mean `foobar = new Foobar();`?

Comment: @DaveNewton: oops sorry for the typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, case sensitive.  Your error states `FooBar()` when your class is named `Foobar()`

Perhaps you are using a different version of the class at runtime to the one you expect. In particular, the runtime class would be different to the one you've compiled against (else this would have caused a compile-time error) - has that method ever been private? Do you have old versions of the classes/jars on your system anywhere?

As the javadocs for `IllegalAccessError` state,

> Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.

I'd definitely look at your classpath and check whether it holds any surprises.

Answer (score 2):

Foobar had previously a `void methodA(String s)`. At that time the Foobar using class was compiled.

This using class should have been recompiled after changing the signature of methodA to `void methodA()`.

This did not happen, and hence the error.

The clue: tried to access method package.FooBar.methodA([Ljava/lang/String;)V

This is `void methodA(java.lang.String)`